# Shell: How to cut a single string with "Cut"?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, cut, io-redirection

i'm trying to cut a string into the shell. I'd like to do something like:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 "hello 12345 xyz"
```

but the problem is that cut accept a file, so if i pass the string to it, it tries to open the unexistent file called "hello 12345 xyz" and then tries to cut its content

I'd like to resolve this problem with the base programs, so don't tell me to use awk

thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You can use `Here Strings` in `BASH`:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 <<< "hello 12345 xyz"
hello
```

Comment: oh, i misunderstood that he was trying to cut the string `hello 12345 xyz` from a file. But you interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 5):

To get `cut` to act on a string instead of a file, you have to give it the string via STDIN. The most common way to do so is this:

```
$ echo 'hello 12345 xyz' | cut -f 1
hello
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this in `bash` itself. If your string is already in a parameter (or you don't mind assigning it to one, you can use `read`:

```
str="hello 12345 xyz"
read first rest <<< "$str"
```

or parameter expansion:

```
echo "${str% *}"
```

or regular expression matching:

```
[[ "hello 12345 xyz" =~ ([^ ]+)\  ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand if you are needing this in a shell script, or when cutting the argument passed to a script, so I'll present solutions for both tasks. Note that not even `cut` is needed, since the shell can perform word-splitting based on white space by default with the `set` builtin.

If you have the string **in** a shell script,

```
 foo="hello 12345 xyz"
 set -- $foo
 echo $1    # hello
```

If the string is **passed** as the first argument to a shell script, as in `script "hello 12345 xyz"`,

```
 set -- $1
 echo $1
```